# Como adiciono uma matriz numa aresta do grafo?

Tags: java

O meu grafo esta implementado como uma matriz de adjacência. O grafo é acíclico. Pretendo criar um método que recebe dois nós e cria uma aresta de um no para outro com uma matriz de NxM. O que esta faltando ou o que esta de errado?

```
public class Graph {

    /** Atributos da classe Graph */

    int [][] grafoo; // o grafo está representada por uma matriz de adjacência


    /** Construtor da classe Graph */ 

    public Graph (int dim)
    {
        grafoo = new int [dim][dim];

        int i=0, j;     
        while(i<dim)
        {
            j=0;
            while(j<dim)
            {
                grafoo[i][j]=0;
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }

    /** Definição do Método */

    void add_edge(int i, int j) //recebe dois nós e adiciona ao grafo uma aresta de um nó para outro com uma matriz de NxM.

        int[][] E = new int[N][M];      
        grafoo[i][j]= E;        
    }
```

Comment: Esta pergunta está muito ampla, precisa definir qual o problema que está ocorrendo.

Comment: O problema e que nao sei como adicionar uma matriz a uma aresta. O grafo esta construido de forma a ser representada por uma matriz de adjacencia (ver metodo construtor),  e depois o meu objectivo e criar uma funcao (add_edge)que receba 2 nos e adiciona uma matriz a aresta.

Comment: Sabe se q sempre q o grafo esteja representado por uma matriz de adjacencia e qnd  ha uma aresta entre 2 nos, a respectiva entrada  e 1. No meu caso, eu queria q em vez de representar uma aresta por 1, colocar nessa entrada uma matriz NxM (exemplo 4x5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema no seu atributo `grafoo`, ele é uma matriz de `int` primitivo, quando para receber uma outra matriz, precisar ser mais complexo.

Há duas abordagens:

A primeira é usar o tipo Object no `grafoo`, que facilita muito no acesso a essa segunda matriz, já que basta acessar uma aresta do `grafoo`, que retorna uma matriz, e depois acessar a matriz novamente. O Código ficaria assim:

```
public class Graph {

    /** Atributos da classe Graph */

    Object [][] grafoo; // o grafo está representada por uma matriz de adjacência

    /** Construtor da classe Graph */ 

    public Graph (int dim)
    {
        grafoo = new Object [dim][dim];
        // Nesse caso não precisamos inicializar o grafoo, porque ele ja esta com todos os valores null, se fosse int também não precisaria,
        // já que por ser diferentemente do C, a JVM atribui valor zero para as áreas de memória após a alocação.
    }

    /** Definição do Método */
    public void add_edge(int i, int j) //recebe dois nós e adiciona ao grafo uma aresta de um nó para outro com uma matriz de NxM.
    {
        int[][] E = new int[N][M];      
        grafoo[i][j] = E; // Agora isso é totalmente válido, no caso anterior gerava erro de compilação.        
    }

    public int[][] get_edge(int i, int j)
    {
        return (int[][]) grafoo[i][j]; // Retorna a matriz relativa à aresta i,j
    }

    public void update_edge(int i, int j, int[][] new_edge) // Atualização por sobreescrita
    {
        grafoo[i][j] = new_edge;
    }

    public void update_edge(int i, int j, int k, int l, int value) // Atualização de célula
    {
        int[][] matrix = (int[][]) grafoo[i][j];
        matrix[k][l] = value;
    }
}
```

Essa abordagem é muito mais simples, porém tem o incômodo de que, com a complexidade aumentando, se você mudar o que você guarda dentro das arestas do `grafoo`, você terá que rever todos os locais que acessam o `grafoo` para que não ocorra erro. Expecificamente no `cast` que é feito no `get_edge`.

A segunda alternativa é usar `int[][]` em vez de `Object`, ficando a declaração do `grafoo` assim: `int [][][][]`, o que eu acho muito estranho e mais confuso para acessar, porém qualquer "erro" cometido irá resultar em erro de compilação e não em `runtime` como na primeira alternativa.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela correcção! Pois, o problema estava na definição do grafoo.

Comment: Surgiu-me aqui uma outra questão. E se quiser fazer um outro método, imaginemos que se chama update_egde, em que recebe dois nós e modifica essa matriz q esta entre estes dois nós, ou seja actualizando essa matriz com novas entradas. Como ficaria? Do meu ponto de vista, o código não é igual ao add_edge?

Comment: Seria tipo o get_edge, mas como seria o tipo de atualização? Seria uma matriz nova ou atualizar determinada célula da matriz? Atualizei o exemplo com dois tipos de atualização que eu pensei no momento. Se tiver outra forma que esteja em mente é só avisar.

Comment: seria mais actualizar a matriz toda porque todos os parâmetros nela contida vão sofrer alteração. Duas questões que me surgiram:
1ª `int[][] E = new int[N][M];` tenho que substituir M e N por números? Caso contrário ele está a dar erro nesta linha.
2ª qual o significado do `(int[][])` nesta linha `int[][] matrix = (int[][]) grafoo[i][j];`

Comment: Sobre a primera questão: vc definiu M e N aonde? Não precisam ser numeros fixos, mas é preciso definir M e N antes de usar. Sobre o segundo, isso se chama cast. De uma olhada nesse link ( http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-object-typecasting) para entender melhor como funciona casting no Java.